# How to search through an array without making multiple if statements?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have an if statement:

```
if (logMessages.author.username === botName[0]) {
   return;
}
```

How can I search through an array of 4 strings without making 4 different if statements?

I hope this is enough of an explanation.

Comment: `if(botName.includes(logMessages.author.username))....`

Comment: If you are just checking to see if an element is in an array, you can also use [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: @jharris711 `.findIndex()` would be best to use when you want to know the specific index position of an element, rather than just finding out if an element exists within an array.

Comment: Maybe a function could be useful: `const check = (bot, username) => bot.includes(username)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to find elements in an array.

I can see that you only need to find whether the element exists or not. For that, the best option would be to use `.includes()`. Example : `arrayName.includes("variable")`

For other options, please have a look [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-array-search-methods).